# rails - Paperclip file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

using rails with Paperclip, I can use the following to get the filename during a before_create:

extension = File.extname(photo_file_name).downcase

How do I get JUST the file name.. Right now I have photo_file_name which provides the entire file, titlename.pdf

i need just titlename without the .pdf

Thanks

**Updating with code:**

photo.rb:

```
  before_create :obfuscate_file_name

  #Paperclip for photo
  has_attached_file :photo,
......


private

  def obfuscate_file_name
    extension = File.extname(photo_file_name).downcase
    fileNameOnly = File.basename(photo_file_name).downcase
    self.photo.instance_write(:file_name, "#{fileNameOnly}_#{ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(32)}#{extension}")
  end
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`File.basename`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002541) with the optional `suffix` argument like this:

```
file_name = File.basename(photo_file_name, File.extname(photo_file_name));
```

Works on my machine:

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow makes you wait 6 mins.

Answer (score 23):

Paperclip attachment has the 'original_filename' method for this.

Comment: I'm not sure this will give what the OP wants. They want `a_file`, not `a_file.pdf`?

Comment: Seems like the title of this question is maybe not specific enough. People probably come here searching for "paperclip filename", and find this answer which is the correct answer to that question, so they upvote it even though it's not what the OP of this question asked.

Answer (score 11):

```
user.logo.original_filename
  => 'test.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is set to default, work for all upload.

This example change name file to 'name default' for web, example: `test áé.jpg` to `test_ae_www.foo.com.jpg`

**helper/application_helper.rb**

```
def sanitize_filename(filename)
    fn = filename.split /(?<=.)\.(?=[^.])(?!.*\.[^.])/m
    fn[0] = fn[0].parameterize
    return fn.join '.'
end
```

Create **config/initializers/paperclip_defaults.rb**

```
include ApplicationHelper

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:parameterize_file_name",
    :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:parameterize_file_name",
})

Paperclip.interpolates :parameterize_file_name do |attachment, style|
    "#{sanitize_filename(attachment.original_filename)}_www.foo.com"
end
```

Need restart, after put this code

I hope it help! ;)